X,y coordinates in the drawing area are shifted when other widgets are shown
Please see the attached screenshots to realize the problem. I packed a GTK drawing area with other widgets. When these widgets are shown the coordinates in the drawing area are shifted and so the centering lines are not center drawn. My code is as follows:
    //Let's translate to origin of the drawing area allocation to avoid
//the cross lines to be rotated too
cairo_save(cr);
cairo_identity_matrix(cr);
cairo_translate(cr, allocation.x, allocation.y);

//This to compensate the allocation menubar height gap
//which prevents the horizontal line to be drawn at the center
//I wonder why the coordinates in the drawing area are shifted
//when the blessed menubar is hidden by the TAB key, shouldn't
//they always be 0,0 at the top left?

int menubar_height = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(img->menubar);
if (img->textbox->draw_horizontal_line)
{
    if (gtk_widget_is_visible(img->menubar))
        center_y = menubar_height + center_y;
    else
        center_y = allocation.height / 2;

//Draw the horizontal centering line
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1.0);
    cairo_move_to(cr, 0, center_y - 2);
    cairo_line_to(cr, allocation.width, center_y - 2);
    cairo_stroke(cr);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.8, 0.7, 0.3);
    cairo_move_to(cr, 0, center_y);
    cairo_line_to(cr, allocation.width, center_y);
    cairo_stroke(cr);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cairo_move_to(cr, 0, center_y + 2);
    cairo_line_to(cr, allocation.width, center_y + 2);
    cairo_stroke(cr);
}

// Draw the vertical centering line
if (img->textbox->draw_vertical_line)
{
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1.0);
    cairo_move_to(cr, center_x - 2, 0);
    cairo_line_to(cr, center_x - 2, allocation.height + menubar_height);
    cairo_stroke(cr);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.8, 0.7, 0.3);
    cairo_move_to(cr, center_x, 0);
    cairo_line_to(cr, center_x, allocation.height + menubar_height);
    cairo_stroke(cr);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cairo_move_to(cr, center_x + 2, 0);
    cairo_line_to(cr, center_x + 2, allocation.height + menubar_height);
    cairo_stroke(cr);
}
cairo_restore(cr);

This is how I pack the drawing area instead:
/* Create the image area */
vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(vbox), "valign", GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (right_horizontal_box), vbox, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

img_struct->image_area = gtk_drawing_area_new();
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), img_struct->image_area, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
gtk_widget_set_hexpand(img_struct->image_area, FALSE);
gtk_widget_set_vexpand(img_struct->image_area, FALSE);

gtk_widget_set_halign(img_struct->image_area, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
gtk_widget_set_valign(img_struct->image_area, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
gtk_widget_set_events(img_struct->image_area, 
                                  GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK
                                | GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK
                                | GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK
                                | GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK);

gtk_widget_set_can_focus(img_struct->image_area, TRUE);
gtk_widget_grab_focus(img_struct->image_area);

Can someone explain to me why the 0,0 coords are shifted in the drawing area when other widgets packed together with it are visible?


I have no clue, but a question: What happens if you do not use cairo_identity_matrix()? Is GTK perhaps "doing something" that you are undoing by removing the matrix?

Also what is allocation in your code? According to https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.DrawingArea.html, your callback function gets the width and height via gtk_widget_get_allocated_width() and ...height(). What if you do not do cairo_translate(cr, allocation.x, allocation.y)?

Ok the solution was to avoid resetting the identity matrix and translating to the drawing area allocation x and y but reuse this code with the negative angle:
        cairo_save(cr);
        cairo_translate(cr, img->textbox->x + img->textbox->width / 2, img->textbox->y + img->textbox->height / 2);
        cairo_rotate(cr, -img->textbox->angle);
        cairo_translate(cr, -(img->textbox->x + img->textbox->width / 2), -(img->textbox->y + img->textbox->height / 2));

//draw the lines
cairo_restore(cr);
